# Salesforce integration with TIBCO

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, tibco

I am trying to integrate salesforce with TIBCO. It will be a two way kind of integration. I have generated the Enterprise WSDL and provided it to my client to faciliate login into salesforce. But they are not able to login. Maybe few of the settings in TIBCO is missing. Also when I try consuming there WSDL, I am able to generate the apex class but not able to send the request as the url and ip provided to me is unreachable. I want to know the steps to integrate Salesforce and TIBCO. Can anyone please share there experience with some documents explaining step by step of integration with TIBCO.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [the official Salesforce.com BusinessWorks plug-in](https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-businessworks-salesforce-com-plug-in-2-4-0) ?

Answer (score 0):

For integration of TIBCO BW to SalesForce:

1. Use the TIBCO BusinessWorks ™ Salesforce.com Plug-in
2. Enter the organization's login information: test.salesforce.com (SANDBOX) / login.salesforce.com (PROD)
3. Select WSDL and Metadata.
4. Execute an operation (Upsert/update...)